# File Copy in Python to the Local Network

Tags: python

```
p = "192.168.12.12"
response = os.system("ping " + ip + " -n 1")
if response == 0:
    print("System  is UP !")
else:
    print("System  is DOWN !")
source = input("Enter source file with full path: ")
target = input("Enter target file with full path: ")
target1 = '\\192.168.62.53\d$\cop1.txt'
try:
    copyfile("f:\cop1.txt",target1)
except IOError as e:
    print("Unable to copy file. %s" % e)
    exit(1)
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info())
    exit(1)
print("\nFile copy done!\n")
```

My problem in this code is when I write address in hard_code(Like `target1`) not input when app running the compile show error:

> (No such file or directory: '\192.168.62.53\d$\cop1.txt')

But when I enter the address in running, the program completely runs and the file copied.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash with another backslash, just as you did (unintentionally) with the one backslash that got printed in the error message.

```
target1 = '\\\\192.168.62.53\\d$\\cop1.txt'
```

Another option would be to use triple quotes:

```
target1 = """\\192.168.62.53\d$\cop1.txt"""
```

Furthermore it is better to use os.path.join and have python create the correct path.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK thanks for the edit. Interestingly the following backslashes need not be escaped (in this particular constellation) as neither \d nor \c have any meaning.

Comment: @Ehsanebrahimi Great. Would you care to accept the answer then?